# Error while building Bazel 0.5.3 on ppc64le

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to build bazel 0.5.3 on Ubuntu 16.04, Linux ppc64le. I want to know the required PROTOC and GRPC_JAVA_PLUGIN versions for bazel 0.5.3. 
With protoc 3.2.0 and grpc-java 1.0.0, I'm getting below error-

## ./compile.sh

INFO: You can skip this first step by providing a path to the bazel binary as second argument:
INFO:    ./compile.sh compile /path/to/bazel
  Building Bazel from scratch./opt/DL/protobuf/bin/protoc -Isrc/main/protobuf/ -Isrc/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/ --java_out=/tmp/bazel_ltKtch3G/src --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/pkgbuild/bazel/protoc-gen-grpc-java --grpc_out=/tmp/bazel_ltKtch3G/src src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto
src/main/protobuf/invocation_policy.proto: File not found.
build_event_stream.proto: Import "src/main/protobuf/invocation_policy.proto" was not found or had errors.
build_event_stream.proto:261:3: "blaze.invocation_policy.InvocationPolicy" is not defined.

I think it is because of incompatible protoc/grpc-java version. Kindly help me on this.
Thanks in advance,
Nishidha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the versions here:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/0.5.3/third_party/protobuf
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/0.5.3/third_party/grpc

So it seems Bazel 0.5.3 depends on grpc 1.3.0 and protobuf 3.2.0.

Just to make sure, you did download the distribution archive, right? `compile.sh` doesn't work with cloned git repo.

FYI, you can also try Bazel 0.5.4 as it was released recently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm able to build bazel 0.5.3 using protobuf 3.2.0 and grpc-java 1.3.0 using distribution archive downloaded from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.5.3/bazel-0.5.3-dist.zip.

Comment: Another thing is compile.sh from cloned git repo has been working for me for older bazel version till 0.4.5. For 0.5.3, I'm yet to try if cloned git repo works or not.

Comment: compile.sh does not work from cloned repo by design: https://bazel.build/designs/2016/10/11/distribution-artifact.html